# Solving in terms of $t$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $m=t^3$ for any positive integer $t$, and if $w=m^2 +m,\;$ what is $w$ in terms of $t$ ? 
From what I tried so far I set $m=t^3.$ Thus I get $t^3=t^3\cdot t^2 \cdot t.$ Is this close to the answer?

Comment: Could you have a look at your final equation, and fix the exponent you missed? (typo) Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$w=m^2+m=(t^3)^2+(t^3)$$
Do you know how to simplify $(t^3)^2$ ?

Comment: you multiply the exponents 3 times 2 which gives you t^6

Comment: Yup, that's right! So the final answer is
$$w=t^6+t^3$$

Comment: @Little Jon: correct. So plug it in

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!